# How do I know how ldd resolved the dependency

Tags: linux, dependencies, resolve, ldd, rpath

For a dependency identified by ldd, how do I know whether it used the binary's RPATH or the environment's LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: You could shorten your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and see what `ldd` tells you...

Answer (score 6):

> how do I know whether it used the binary's RPATH or the environment's LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Assuming Linux, run like so:

```
env LD_DEBUG=files,libs /path/to/executable
```

The output will tell you all you want to know: what the loader search path is when looking for various libraries, and why.